# Adobe Air - get device name (such as EVO, DROID X..)

Tags: actionscript, air, adobe

I'm working in Actionscript in Adobe Air, and I want to get a device's model name, such as 'EVO' or 'DROID X'. Has anyone been able to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found it... It is here: android.os.Build.MODEL

Comment: Why is this a downvoted if I post the correct answer since I found it?

Comment: I didn't downvote but your answer is very short, you don't explain how you use it ,if from native extension or from ActionScript code

Answer (score 2):

`Capabilities.os` and `Capabilities.manufacturer` are probably sufficient for identifying an iOS device (iPhone, iPod, iPad, as well as their generation). On Android, the platform you specified, these properties are too general. In my testing, `manufacturer` is "Android Linux" and `os` is "Linux" plus numbers indicating the exact Linux version. This is enough for your code to recognize it's running on Android but little else.

To access device name on Android, you'd need to write or find a Native Extension that returns `android.os.Build.MODEL`. Based on searching, no such extension exists yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Android-Native-Device-Info](https://github.com/funky-monkey/Android-Native-Device-Info) it has device's brand, model, OS version and CPU, LCD Density, etc.

Comment: I didn't see a license or a copyright on the repository, but the source files each have a copyright notice that says, "All Rights Reserved."  Other people have mentioned this library too, but I'm wondering if it's safe to use it?

Comment: @Panzercrisis sorry not sure about that, other wise see my latest answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34408873/1578100

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) class (there are two properties os and manufacturer). I'm not sure if the device name is included in any of this.

Comment: There is some info in there, but not the device name..Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

To get these details (SSID, MAC address and device name) from iOS I found [this ANE from as3 Gamegears](http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/ane-device-info-util/). Github [Project link](https://github.com/katopz/ane-device-info-util).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'm not going to include the code for the whole ANE project on here am I? I've added a direct link to the project on Github as well now, to make the world a better place.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late answer but maybe others still need it. If you looking for Native Extension to get Android device info you can check this [DeviceInfoANE](https://github.com/janumedia/DeviceInfoANE). Feel free to use and modify!