# Get Host name in Adobe AIR ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How can I get the host name using ActionScript3 in Adobe AIR?
I need it to work on both iOS and Android.

**Clarification**: When I say machine name I mean the name given to the machine (or device) by the user, not the type such as iPhone or iPad. I want machine name such as Abc's iPad. Host name.

Comment: I think there is answer on your questenin 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743570/adobe-air-get-device-name-such-as-evo-droid-x

Answer (score 1):

```
package  {

import flash.system.Capabilities;

public class example {

    public function example() {
        trace(Capabilities.os);
    }
}
```

}

Should work easy, there's an official documentation on adobe help : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os

Comment: Thanks but that give the name of the OS, not the name of the machine assign to it by the user.

Comment: @IdoRan you can't with only actionScript, it doesn't have the "right" to see these informations. At least on iOS. With android you can access it with the .apk but there's no native code to use it on AS3. You can't say (example) : trace("Hi "+this.userName+" !");