# Fullscreen on phone with notch or detecting if the device has notch with Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How to use fullscreen on android phone with notch or detecting if the device has notch and the size of notch or get the x,y coordinates of the native android application from Adobe AIR(I'm using AIR.32)?

I have created an Adobe AIR application that is not displayed correctly in fullscreen on Android phones that have screen with notch. On such phones my app is cropped as the entire app is shifted to the right because of the notch.

[image: screenshot]

My question is can I detect the size of notch or the x/y coordinate of the AIR native application so I can make appropriate corrections.

My app is set to run in fullscreen and with no scaling:
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

Comment: If you use an ANE you could retrieve the model information and from there you could handle all known cases, not clean but functional as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743570/adobe-air-get-device-name-such-as-evo-droid-x

Comment: Hi, I'm considering it like my final option. Thanks.

Comment: There may be something new in the last few years but previously ... your app has to try to figure out what the device is. For some dark reason, phones do not have their information available, they don't give manufacturer, screen dimensions, model number, etc. Your app has to get what info it can and figure out for itself. It's not too bad, you can check screen dimensions against a list of the top phones and figure out a lot